# Example of wake up waiting bit not working for multiple producers or consumers

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, synchronization, semaphore

In Andrew Tanenbaum's book about Operating Systems, in the section about the Consumer/Producer problem, he gives an example about a system consisting of one producer, which insert data blocks in a buffer, and a consumer, which gets them, taking them out of the buffer. Also, there is a counter, which keeps track of the number of data blocks in the buffer. When the consumer verifies that the counter is zero, it sleeps. When the produces verifies that the counter is zero, and puts some data in the buffer, it sends a wake up signal to the consumer.

This can lead to racing conditions, in a well known manner, and Tanenbaum gives a possible solution, using a wake up waiting bit. If the consumer receives a wake up signal while still wake, the wake up waiting bit is set to one. Before sleeping, it verifies the bit. If one, it decreases the bit to zero and does not sleep.

This solves the problem for one producer and one consumer. But Tanenbaum states that, when three or more producer/consumer threads are involved, it is easy to think of an example where the wake up waiting bit does not prevent racing conditions.

I could not think of such an example, and all sources about producer/consumer problem and semaphores seem to avoid the same point.

Can some one please provide such an example of three or more processes (preferably three) where the wake up waiting bit does not prevent a racing condition?

Answer (score 1):

The apparent problem here is that you are dealing with primitive locking mechanisms that no competent programmer would use in real life. Any rationally-designed operating system will have locking mechanisms that are more sophisticated then just setting bits and counters.

Some operating systems have a lock manager. For such a queue you could define a named write lock. All the producers and consumers try to take out exclusive write locks and all the mechanism you describe would be implemented in terms of operating system services.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the motivation behind semaphores, as Tanenbaum tries to justify them. More precisely, why use an integer and not a single bit? Why is a single bit not enough? It is enough for a one producer / one consumer problem. So, for, say, two producers and one consumer, what would be a practical example of a race condition?